# jquery fadeIn does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to fadeOut and fadeIn several images after calling a function fade().

```
<img src="./img/01-text.jpg" name="./img/01-text.jpg" onload="fade()" />
```

There is a function fade():

```
function fade(){    
    var name = $('.slidy').find('img').attr('name');
    if( name == "./img/01-text.jpg"){
        function goAhead(){
            $('.slidy img').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000, 
                function(){
                    $(this).attr("src", "./img/02-text.jpg");
                        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
                    $('.slidy img').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000,
                        function(){
                            $(this).attr("src", "./img/03-text.jpg");
                            $(this).fadeIn(1000);
                            goAhead().stop();
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
        goAhead();
    }
    else{
        alert( "not found" );
    }
}
```

When I call the function for first fadeOut and fadeIn it works. But when I call it for a second time, image just fades out but does not fadeIn anymore. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Would you mind dropping this into a code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: goAhead().stop(); when the function excuted for the first time at the end this line stop the animation